# Tricky screen sizing and scaling (on Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, websocket

I have a tricky question that might just have a simple solution, although I trully don't see it now.

So, I've been working around HTML5  element and, obviously, doing the interaction methodology in JavaScript.

One of the objectives of this work is to be able to use a mobile device [MD] (iOS or Android, phone or tablet) as a remote controller for an application that will be served by another machine (eg. a laptop or external display) and both will be showing the same thing on each of the screens on different scales.

So, I wanna have an event occur when the canvas is 80% filled (or in this case, "erased" (which I already have by calculating the total number of [initial] pixels) and each device has a different count since the screen sizes/resolutions are different.

This is the tricky part: How will I be able to "scale" the MD pixel count and mirror that to the bigger screen?

For concrete measures, how will I be able to implement the following example:

I draw a line on the MD that goes for 300px wide, and for simplicity, let's say that this represents 10% of the MD canvas (which on both the screens is in fullscreen).
I want the external monitor (which has a higher resolution) to mirror this event but on an appropriate scale so that those 10% on the MD represent the same (scaled) 10% of "canvas real estate"

Just in case the text is too confusing, I'll leave the code bellow:

```
function totalPix(x, y) {
    var total = x * y;
    var objective = (total * 80) / 100;
}

function canvasApp() {

//prevent from scrolling (no bouncing)
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);

if(!canvasSupport()) {
    alert("No canvas support on this device!");
    return;
} else if(!socketSupport) {
            alert("No websocket support on this device!");
        } else {

    //create canvas on every load (//TODO)
    var elemDiv = document.getElementById("content");
    var newElem = document.createElement("canvas");
    newElem.setAttribute("id", "frontscreen");
    elemDiv.appendChild(newElem);

    drawScreen();

    function drawScreen() {

        //Setup canvas
        var canvas = document.getElementById("frontscreen");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        totalPix(canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();

        //Foreach touchmove event, send position to server
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
            for (var i = 0; i<event.touches.length; i++) {
                var touch = event.touches[i];
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
                ctx.fillStyle = "white";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(touch.pageX, touch.pageY, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }, false); 
    window.onresize = function resizeCanvas() {drawScreen();};
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it's as simple as changing the size property on the HTML style property of your `<canvas>` element. For example, let's say you fill in a 300 by 300 px. square on Monitor A, which occupies 10% of the screen real estate (I know, big monitor). Then you load the same page on Monitor B, which is twice the size of Monitor A. (Really really big monitor, just bear with me here. It's an example.) Naturally, it will only occupy 5% of the screen's real estate.

If you want that 300px to always occupy the same percentage of size on all screens (but still be 300px on the canvas), you can do something like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var heightAsPercent = 10;
var widthAsPercent = 10;
canvas.style.height = (heightAsPercent / 100) * screen.height;
canvas.style.width = (widthAsPercent / 100) * screen.width;
```

That way, the canvas will *always* occupy 10% of the screen, whether the monitor width is 3000px or 6000px. I've obviously chosen very verbose variable names for clarity, so feel free to modify them as needed.

The reason this works is that you're only modifying the CSS properties of the canvas, which affect only how it's rendered, not the actual `<canvas>` data. I came across this little trick by accident, and it drove me nuts until I figured out why it was doing this. Now it actually comes in handy. :)

Comment: I don't need the canvas to scale since it already does whatever the screen size. What i want is that every 'object' draw on screenA is scaled and translated to screenB. Please, see the example on [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3543277/raspadinha/index.html) and use it in a mobile device and a PC browser to see if that helps :)